# Show that a function $f:P(X)\to P(X)$ preserving the subset relation has a fixed point

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, fixed-point-theorems

We have a map $f:P(X)\to P(X)$, where $P(X)$ means the part of $X$ and the function is  monotone (by considering inclusion "$\subseteq$"). So $\forall \space A\subseteq B $ we have $f(A)\subseteq f(B)$.
Show that this map has a fixed point.

This claim is used in some proofs of [Cantor–Schröder–Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem), for example, see [proof 3](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cantor-Bernstein-Schr%C3%B6der_Theorem#Proof_3) on ProofWiki ([current revision](https://proofwiki.org/w/index.php?title=Cantor-Bernstein-Schr%C3%B6der_Theorem&oldid=306562#Proof_3)).

Comment: Hi -- please [choose a good title](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144) for your questions. In the question itself, by the "part of $X$" you mean the power set?

Comment: See also: [Knaster–Tarski theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Tarski_theorem). (This is a more general claim for any complete lattice $(L,\le)$ and  a monotone function $f\colon L\to L$.)

Comment: As pointed out in a [related discussion on meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28692/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-07-2018-today/30420#30420), there is also this related question: [Every increasing function from a certain set to itself has at least one fixed point](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/791411).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll generalize the nice answer by @Brian and give a curiosity (that you don't need to show that there exists at least one $A \subset X$ such that $A \subset f(A)$!).

*Definition:* Given a partially ordered set $X$ and a subset $A$, $\sup(A)$ is defined as (if it exists) the element $s$ such that:

1. $s\geq a ~\forall a \in A$.
2. $b \geq a ~\forall a \in A \implies b \geq s$.

Uniqueness is clear. Note that $\emptyset$ has a $\sup$ if and only if $A$ has a minimum element.

Now, we have:

**Theorem:** Let $X$ be partially ordered s.t. every subset has a supremum and $f:X \to X$ monotone. Then $f$ has a fixed point.

*Proof:* Let $A=\{x \mid f(x) \geq x\}$. Take $s=\sup(A)$ (note that this is exactly the set given by Brian).

We prove that $f(s)=s$.

First, since $s$ is $\sup(A)$, it follows that $s \geq x $ for all $x \in A$. Since $f$ is monotone, we have $f(s) \geq f(x)$ for all $x \in A$. Since $f(x)\geq x$ for all $x \in A$, we have $f(s) \geq x$ for all $x \in A$. Since $s$ is $\sup(A)$, it follows that $f(s) \geq s$.

Now, note that monotonicity implies $f(f(s)) \geq f(s)$. Therefore, $f(s) \in A$. We then have $s \geq f(s)$, since $s$ is $\sup(A)$.

It follows that $s=f(s)$. $\blacksquare$

Note that in no point of the proof we needed $A$ to be non-empty, although it clearly is (since the set will have a minimum element by assumption).

Now your exercise is to adapt the proof to your case.

Comment: Would there be an alternative to proving this theorem where you inductively define $g(0) = \varnothing$, $g(\alpha^+) = f(g(\alpha))$ and $g(\lambda) = \bigcup \{ g(\alpha) : \alpha < \lambda \}$ for limit ordinal $\lambda$. If there is no fixed point, then since $g$ is monotone, it is an injection from the ordinals into $\mathcal{P}$ which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 10):

HINT: Consider the set $\bigcup\{A\subseteq X:A\subseteq f(A)\}$. (Be sure to show that there is at least one $A\subseteq X$ such that $A\subseteq f(A)$.)