# If $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ is increasing function. Suppose $0<f(0),f(1)<1$. Show $f$ has fixed point.

Tags: real-analysis, monotone-functions

A Fixed point of $f$ is a point $r$ such that $f(r)=r$.

I am not really convinced by this theorem holds for any function (even discontinuous functions). For example, I sketched this function:

[image]

This function has $f(0)>0, f(1)<1$, it is increasing and has no value $r$ where $f(r)=r$. Am I missing something or did the question miss a condition?

Comment: What is $f(r)$? Your conditions state that $f$ is defined everywhere.

Comment: Yeah, you should definitely explain more clearly what you think is a counterexample.

Comment: @Any: the theorem remains true if you replace monotonicity with continuity, but continuity need not be added to monotonicity.

Comment: @mlc I think I got confused a bit by discontinuity and being undefined. I think I figured out the proof. Let $S=\{x:f(x)-x\geq 0\}$. $S$ is bounded above by $1$ so $SupS$ exists. Similarly for $S'=\{x:f(x)-x\leq 0\}$ and bounded below by $0$ so $InfS'$ exists. We must have $SupS=InfS'=r$ since otherwise it would contradict their definition. Also, we have by monotone function theorem $f(r-)\leq f(r) \leq f(r+)$ but $f(r+)\leq r$ and $f(r-)\geq r$ so $r\leq f(r) \leq r$ or $f(r)=r$

Answer (score 2):

The function you provided is not defined in $[0,1]$.

As $f(0)>0$, the function $f$ will be over the line $y=x$ when $x=0$. Similarly, $f$ will be below the line $y=x$ when $x=1$. Then, the key here is to find a point where the function happens to go from over the line to below the line without touching it. Let's suppose this point is $r$. This is:

$\forall x < r : f(x) > x$
And 
$\forall x > r : f(x) < x$

Also, as the function is defined for every point in the interval $[0,1]$ and it is always increasing, 
$\forall \eta \in [0,1] f(\eta)<f(\xi) ~\forall\xi>\eta$

So, if we assume that $f(r) > r$, then for $ r+\epsilon$, $f(r+\epsilon)<r+\epsilon$ but as the function is increasing, $f(r+\epsilon)>f(r)$. When doing $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$, we obtain that $f(r)$ is both $>r$ and $<r$. Which is a contradiction.

Similar result is obtained supposing $f(r) < r$ with $f(r-\epsilon)>r-\epsilon$. The only option to avoid the contradiction is by selecting $r$ such as $f(r)=r$.

Another approach could be analysing the function $g(x)= f(x)-x$ and proving that $g(r)=0$.

Comment: How to you go from *"find a point where ..."* to *"Let's suppose this point is $r$"*? In other words, how exactly is $r$ defined? Also note that there can be multiple intervals where the graph of $f$ lies below or above the diagonal, see the second image in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/791470/42969.